# C++ Alternative to SFML Audio with MP3/M4A/Metadata/GetSamples support

Tags: c++, audio, sfml

I'm currently using SFML Audio for my visualizer and it works great but some of the limitations are causing problems. Currently my music library consists of MP3 and M4A files and I'm not keen on having to convert them every time I make additions to the library. I'm also looking for a way to read metadata from MP3 and M4A files so that I can list the title, album, and artist. I would you iTunes' exported playlist to get that info yet it only lists the title of the song. Since this is a visualizer I also need to be able to get at least 8192 samples per channel at the current audio position in order to produce the visualization. And lastly I'm hoping to be able to stream media instead of loading it all at once so that there's not a short pause when switching songs. What are some alternatives that support these features?

1. Must work with Windows.
2. C++ Library for loading/playing audio (I can make due with C if need be)
3. Supports MP3/M4A
4. Supports Reading metadata (Optionally on alternative library)
5. Supports getting sample data at the current position in the song (at least 8192 samples in advance)
6. Supports streaming media instead of loading it all at once to prevent lag on switching songs.

Comment: You tried JUCE yet?

Comment: @learnvst I'll take a look right now. Thanks.

Comment: @learnvst I'm reading up on it and it seems things are separated by plugins and another IDE. Is there anyway to use just the audio plugin as well as Visual Studio 2015 as the IDE? Another issue I read is that M4a seems to be supported for iOS, OSX devices but I can't find anything saying they're supported on Windows.